# While Loop Won't return all values of a given record

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

I am new to PHP and coding:

For each record, the function below only returns the "code" variable values in $myChallenge.  However, I need the other variable values (e.g. partnerName, challengeTitle, image_url) for each record in order to use them in subsequent functions that use $myChallenge.

---

### Controller

```
public function getChallenge(){
    //challengenames
    $link=$this->dbPrototype();
    $query="select * from challengestable where status=0 ORDER BY date DESC";
    $result=$link->query($query);
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $myChallenge[$row['challengeId']] = $row;
    }
    return $myChallenge;
}




public function viewChallengesAction(){
        //get instance for request
    $request = JO_Request::getInstance();
        //get activated challengenames
    $myChallenge=$this->getChallenge();
    $this->view->challengenames = array();
    foreach($myChallenge AS $k=>$challengename){
        $this->view->challengenames[$k]['href'] = WM_Router::create($request->getBaseUrl() . '?module=challenges&controller=index&action=yourChallenge?code=' . $k);
        $this->view->challengenames[$k]['title'] = $challengename['title'];
    }
```

---

### View

```
<?php if ($this->challengenames && is_null($this->tag)) { ?>
    <div id="browsecats">
        <div class="list">
            <ul>
                <?php foreach($this->challengenames as $k=>$challengename) { ?>
                    <li><a href="<?php echo $challengename['href']; ?>"><?php echo $challengename['title']; ?></a></li>
                <?php } ?>
            </ul>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php }?>
```

=============

## ViewChallenge

```
<?php echo $this->header_part; ?>

<div id="defaultcontainerwrapper" class="maxwidth">
    <?php foreach($this->challengenames as $k=>$challengename) { ?>
        <header>
            <h1>
                <div class="list">
                    <span>Welcome to </span><?php echo $challengename['partnerName']; ?><span>'s Beat Waste Challenge!</span>
                </div>
            </h1>
        </header>
    <?php } ?>
</div>

<?php echo $this->footer_part; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the entire row into `$myChallenge`:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $myChallenge[$row['code']] = $row;
}
```

Now `$myChallenge` will be a 2-dimensional array. You can access values like

```
$myChallenge[$code]['partnerName'];
```

Comment: Hi Barmar,

Thanks very much for the help. I can now see all the variables in my debugger, which is great!  However,  I am failing to correctly use your second reference - $myChallenge[$code]['partnerName']; - to access other variable values.

For example, in the parent function (pasted below), instead of displaying the "code" value as $k, I would now like to display the "partnerName" value but when I try to declare your reference, it doesn't work.

Again, thanks so much for any assistance.  Code to follow.

Comment: Added code above to original post for formatting. Tx again!

Comment: I think the last line should be something like `$this->view->challengenames[$k]['title'] = $challengename['title'];`

Comment: Got it.  Thanks so much:  I actually replaced last line with: $this->view->challengenames[$k]['title'] = $challengename['partnerName'];

Comment: Sorry to bother you one last time, Barmar.  I have solved that first issue perfectly. Now, I am in another loop issue: I have a for each loop that correctly returns multiple records.  My question is how do I limit it to only return for the current record?    I have added the code under "ViewChallenge".